# Specify no check certificate for npm dependency?

Tags: tls, wireshark

I'm trying to install a private gitlab repo in my project.

My `package.json` contains:

```
"dependencies": {
  "<my-private-repo>": "git+https://<token>@<server>/<user>/<repo>.git"
}
```

When I launch:

```
npm install --save
```

I get the following error:

> `SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate.`

I currently correct it by doing :

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
npm install --save
git config --global http.sslVerify true
```

However, using this workaround, all dependencies are affected.

How can I specify a `sslVerify` `false` to THIS dependency only?

Answer (score 2):

According to RFC8446 for TLS1.3 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446), all of the parameters that you listed in your question are either ephemeral keys, or values derived from ephemeral keys.  Therefore, these values can be used to decrypt ciphertext that was sent during the session that you captured in your trace, but could not be used to decrypt ciphertext that was sent in previous sessions or subsequent sessions.

EDIT 12/3/2019 2:01 PM EST:  This question was edited and changed to a very different question than the one that I answered above less than an hour ago.

Comment: @guest348342083049 if you can guarantee that sessions that were captured don't persist, no.